# How to restore/recreate etc/resolv.conf files

Tags: restore, resolv.conf

I deleted both the `resolvconf` folder and the `resolv.conf` file in `/etc` by mistake, assuming  that resolvconf was causing UCK to fail. Now the application has upgraded, fixing the issue, but it says `no file named resolv.conf in /etc`. 
What it says is correct because I deleted those files. Is there any way to recreate the files or restore from another location?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could reinstall resolvconf to restore the default configuration:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall resolvconf
```

Another idea would be remove "resolvconf" and then install:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

Comment: Amplification: to ensure that resolvconf is fully restored you have to purge it and install it again, then reboot. If you don't purge it but only remove it then it won't install the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf on reinstall. If you don't reboot then resolvconf's database will generally be missing nameserver information until you do reboot... or reconfigure (down and up) all active interfaces.

Comment: This broke my internet, and now I can't fetch any packages from the ubuntu repos.

Comment: This also broke internet, uninstalled, reinstall failed, and now I cant update anything.

Comment: If you find yourself unable to fetch new packages, ping `us.archive.ubuntu.com` on another computer, grab the straight IP address returned and use that in a `wget` (ie: `wget http://91.189.91.26/ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf/resolvconf_1.78ubuntu4_all.deb`) then install using `dkpg` (ie: `dpkg -i resolvconf_1.78ubuntu4_all.deb`) and reboot. Alternative would be to put the IP in your `/etc/hosts` just to get the update/install to complete.

Comment: ln: cannot remove '/etc/resolv.conf': Device or resource busy

Comment: @vandsh the link `ubuntu/pool/main/r/resolvconf` is not valid, under `r` is no resolvconf.

Comment: When you're dealing with a file that controls whether the computer can resolve domain names, please do not suggest uninstalling something and then reinstalling it when reinstalling it will not work when DNS is broken.

Answer (score 17):

If `resolvconf -u` shows the WARNING that `/etc/resolv.conf` is not a symbolic link to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` then just backup that *resolv.conf* and make the symbolic link:

```
$ cd /etc
$ sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! How would you reinstall resolvconf when you can't resolve hostnames?!

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

add:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

nameserver 192.168.x.x 
(check your `ifconfig` output for the correct address)

then

```
sudo service resolvconf start
sudo systemctl enable resolvconf
```

Comment: re-installing resolvconf is probably a better idea

Comment: This would only affect things temporarily.  The /etc/resolv.conf file would be overwritten since it's managed by the resolvconf package.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer did not work for me. After reinstalling `resolvconf`, the system would completely wipe my `resolv.conf` file after each reboot.

To fix this, I had to reinstall the `network-manager` and `libnss-resolve` packages in addition to `resolvconf`.

1. Manually add a nameserver to resolve.conf (this is so you can fetch packages from the Ubuntu repos):

   1. ```
      sudo vi /etc/resolv.conf
      ```
   2. Add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the file.
2. Reinstall the `network-manager`,  `libnss-resolve`, and `resolvconf` packages:

   ```
   apt install --reinstall resolvconf network-manager libnss-resolve
   ```

Comment: Good answer. If your dns resolution is broken, this gets you back to working, so you can effect other repairs.

Answer (score -2):

Have you emptied your trash, if not, you can restore from trash.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I never used delete alone but shift+delete,so not in trash.

Comment: I see.  Try to use a recovery program, i.e foremost.  Or try to do what @desgua said.

Comment: Seriously... Who uses "trash"? If you're going to delete a file like this, you do it from the command line.