# ExpressVPN - can not use internet while disabled (disconnected)

Tags: networking, vpn

I was surfing the Internet, and suddenly (I didn't do anything, did change any settings, only were using browser) - Interned disappeared. I thought something with the router, I rebooted it, then my phone and the other Ubuntu-PC successfully reconnected, but my notebook Can not access any server. Looks like there is no Internet.

But if I start `expressvpn connect` it can successful access its servers and establish the connection, and than my browser can show web pages.

What happened, how to reset this behavior? I can not access Internet with VPN being connected.

I tried this
[How do I reset my Network settings to default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835195/how-do-i-reset-my-network-settings-to-default) - doesn't work, can see any wifi networks.
Also I flushed `/etc/network/interfaces` - doesn't help.

I tried reinstall ExpressVPN too - didn't help.

How to get back the default behavior. I don't want reinstall Ubuntu, it's not Windows, when you do it every time something doesn't work, right?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [How to restore/recreate etc/resolv.conf files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134121/how-to-restore-recreate-etc-resolv-conf-files)

Specifically:
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install resolvconf

That fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo apt install resolvconf` then disconnect expressvpn

Comment: I believe `resolvconf` is installed by default. If so, this wouldn't do anything. Is `resolvconf` removed by ExpressVPN installation or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf` after disconnecting expressvpn.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem and not solve it completely.i tried many ways(include resolvconf / reinstall expressvpn/reinstall other version expressvpn and so on),all doesnot work!
Now,when i want to disconnect the expressvpn, first to disconnect wifi ,then disconnect expressvpn,and turn on wifi. maybe a bit of trouble to operation.