# After each reboot cannot resolve host by Dns

Tags: 16.04, dns

After each reboot Ubuntu cannot resolve host by DNS and cannot open any page.
I use to run these commands after each reboot to make everything work

```
rm /etc/resolv.conf 
sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo resolvconf -u
```

How can I avoid that issue?

Comment: Could this possibly be related to this bug?
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-the-march-2017-ubuntu-dns-resolution-issues

Comment: hi, similar question ? >  https://askubuntu.com/a/134137/397428

Comment: If you could add the info in the non-working resolv.conf to your question, that could be helpful. @Yolateng0, similar in symptom, but very different causes and broken states. It would seem he does have a resolv.conf, albeit a useless one, whereas the user in the other question errantly deleted config files.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're already trying to use the solution described here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/280264/no-dns-resolution-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-14-04-to-16-04

While not ideal, a work-around would be to automatically run your commands on boot. This page includes some methods of doing that:

http://linuxtechlab.com/executing-commands-scripts-at-reboot/

Another possibility is that you're affected by the bug in the March 2017 update:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-the-march-2017-ubuntu-dns-resolution-issues

Another very thorough answer appears here:
[16.10 fail to resolve DNS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838948/16-10-fail-to-resolve-dns)

I don't know enough about your precise circumstances to advise a particular one of these to try first, but hopefully one of them will work for you.

**Update:** Based on the knowledge that it's failing when the server reboots with a non-standard VPN client up, it's reasonable to assume that this VPN client could be modifying resolv.conf and removing some of the default entries in an attempt to avoid DNS leakage. I would recommend then making sure that your VPN client is disconnected before shutdown, and possibly still automatically resetting the resolv.conf after boot.

Alternatively, you could try adding a legitimate nameserver of your choice, such as `nameserver 8.8.8.8` to the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`, which might help. I am not sure if this will affect functionality of your VPN or not, or cause DNS leaking, so use it cautiously. Source:
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2352821&page=2

Comment: It happens only if Vpn connection was on, before the reboot. I'm using PulseSecure client

Comment: Are you using NetworkManager?

Comment: For VPN I use a separate client

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not super familiar with that client or service, and can't seem to find any suitable resources on it. I would recommend trying the first approach; running the commands you're already using to fix it immediately after reboot. Additionally, knowing the contents of the broken resolv.conf after reboot could prove helpful.

Comment: Not a solution, but could provide you some insight: 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273050/how-to-know-where-resolv-conf-entries-come-from

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like something (perhaps your PulseSecure client) is overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf` or `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` the latter by default should contain the following:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

the former as you know is supposed to be a symbolic link to the latter. You might check these files prior to reboot to insure they are unchanged. or better yet `watch` them for changes to determine when and why the modification occurs.

Comment: That's the suspicion I had as well, once he mentioned it.