# Windscribe VPN not working for some reason

Tags: vpn

It's working on my browser but it doesn't work on my Kubuntu 18.04 I installed all the keys and stuff they recommended then installed the windscribe-cli and signed in, when I try to connect it says firewall enabled and under it there's a spinning thingy that doesnt stop like it can't connect. Can you help me fix the issue?

The problem is on my Linux because I can connect to their servers when I use the browser[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hXPI.png)

Edit: I have UFW blocking all incoming connections, could it be causing the problem?

Edit2: I disabled UFW and I still can't connect to the VPN :(

Comment: Try again here https://windscribe.com/guides/manual_ubuntu or for best results use their native Linux app https://windscribe.com/guides/linux

Answer (score 1):

I use Windscribe on Ububtu 18.04 and I have noticed that once you are logged in you remain logged in and also once enabled the firewall stays enabled ( the windscribe firewall blocks all internet access when not connected to a windscribe server), even after a restart.
I would recommend disabling the firewall with the commend "windscribe firewall off" then try to reconnect then after connection turn the firewall back on.
Alternately try a different location from the locations list but remember to use the pseudonym for example "windscribe connect castle" is Frankfurt Germany.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the firewall is defeating the purpose of using a **VPN** ( your IP address won't change). This what I did to make it work again in **Ubuntu 18.04**:

Remove **resolvconf** and then reinstall it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf && sudo apt-get install resolvconf
```

#### Don't forget to reboot!

Comment: This worked for me. After reboot I had to reinstall windscribe then it worked.

Comment: This didn't work for me and broke my internet connection. I was able to restore it following the solution given under [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134121/how-to-restore-recreate-etc-resolv-conf-files#134137).

Comment: @horseoftheyear Ironically that's the same command line in the other post!

Comment: Apologies: With *given under* I meant the solution to restoring internet connection - given under the answer by one of the comments - after the command *given by* the answer broke it.

Answer (score 0):

Small note: The firewall has literally no impact on whether you're using a VPN or not. The Firewall is basically just a killswitch; it kills your connection if your vpn connection is disrupted/lost, so you don't connect using your own connection.